# SQL Server Express Connection error using python

Tags: python

```
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets]Specified SQL server not found. (6) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (11001); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')
```

I getting this error everytime whenever i am trying

i want to build connection using python in sql server express

Comment: Share your connecting string by hiding sensible information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.